# wso2 xslt mediator with namespaces

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

we want to use an xslt mediator to transform a xml in other.
  we have this soap message.

```
  <?xml version = "1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.es">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:reception>
         <ws:xml>
           <message>Data messsage to send</message>
         </ws:xml>
      </ws:reception>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

And we want this message as result.

```
  <?xml version = "1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ws="http://ws.es">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:reception>
         <ws:xml>
           <![CDATA[<message>Data messsage to send]]></message>
         </ws:xml>
      </ws:reception>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

we are using this xslt template

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "ISO-8859-1"?> 
<xsl:stylesheet version = "1.0" xmlns:xsl = "http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

   <xsl:template match = "//ws:xml"> 
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> &lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
             <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
         <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> ]]&gt;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:copy>   
    </xsl:template>  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

But it doesn't work.

can anyone help us??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your two files are identical. But if I'm right in thinking you want to change

```
<message>Data messsage to send</message>
```

into

```
<message><![CDATA[Data messsage to send]]></message>
```

if so try the below:

(**code has been edited to reflect updated question**)

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="message">
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> &lt;![CDATA[</xsl:text>
    <message>
        <xsl:value-of select="//message"/>
    </message>
    <xsl:text disable-output-escaping="yes"> ]]&gt;</xsl:text>      
</xsl:template>
```

Be warned though, Michael Kay will shout at you for using `disable-output-escaping`

Comment: I'm sorry. We want <![CDATA[<message>Menssage data</message>]]>

Comment: ok thanks. However, if we include a xml tag into message xml tag, this template delete the tag and it only shows the content of the tag, like  <![CDATA[<message> data </message>]]>.., it should show .....<![CDATA[<message><tag>data</tag></message>]]>....

Comment: ok, if i use xsl:copy-of instead of xsl:value-of, we have what we want.  Thanks a lot for you quick answer and your atention.